# Reduce AES-CTR malleability impact by shuffling plain text

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I need to cipher and decipher text with randomly access. For this I decided to use AES in CTR mode which is a good compromise between CBC and GCM.

**But CTR mode is malleable**. It is not a big problem because texts that **I will cipher have not predefine patterns and I don’t need authentication**, I just want to avoid the ability to read the plain text for an attacker.

However, **I want to reduce the ability to an attacker to really use the malleability property of CTR.**

Here my idea to do it:

```java
public static void main() {
    Key key = …;
    IVParameterSpec iv = …;
    int rSeed = …;
    byte[] plainText = …;
   
    byte[] shuffled = shuffle(plainText, rSeed);
    byte[] encrypted = encryptAES_CTR(shuffled, key, iv);

    …

    byte[] decrypted = decryptAES_CTR(encrypted, key, iv);
    byte[] unShuffled = unShuffle(decrypted, rSeed);

    // Here unShuffled content must be equal to plainText content.
}
```

Suppose that methods `shuffle(…)` and `unShuffle(…)` are complementary and one reverse the other.

The shuffle step is here not to cipher but shuffle the order of bytes of the plain text, **in that way it reduces the impact of modifications done on the ciphered text by an attacker** because if an attacker changes a part of the ciphered text, **the modifications will be spread during the unShuffle phase** and will change the content but the chance that the new content can be exploitable is reduced.

**However, it is just an idea and I write this post just to know if this idea is really useful or if it is useless and just superficial step which does not reduce the impact of modifications that can be done by an attacker on the ciphered text.**

I know that there is the GCM which provides authentication and therefore, is not malleable. But I don’t really need it and GCM cannot be accessed randomly especially if I want modify and re cipher just a part of the plain text.

Comment: There are definitely problems with your approach. You are better off to ask on [crypto.se] instead of here though. If you do, please describe how you want to perform random access **after** you shuffled the plaintext? What do you think happens if you perform changes to part of the plaintext / ciphertext? Won't an attacker then know which bits are being altered? For ideas on how to perform authentication, take a look at Merkle trees.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I simplify my model, however I don’t shuffle the plain text totally but I shuffle 128 bits block by 128 bits block (because AES cipher 128bits). In that way I decipher a block a just unShuffle only this block.